# Spike Test using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am doing spike test using Apache JMeter. 
My test scenario is to create booking on a website. 
I am using sync timer to generate spike at the create booking.
How can i verify spike is actually generated after test is finished ?

Comment: Verify from Jmeter side, You can use Listeners "Active Threads OverTime, Connect Thread OverTime, Hits Per Second" ; It will show you the spikes generated from your LG machines

Answer (score 0):

to validate a spike in requests, you need to add a listener that will plot all the requests hitting your server over time.

there's a plugin that can help you do it:
https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use custom thread group instead of using the default thread group. Please check [JMeter Plugins website.](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

- Stepping Thread Group
- Ultimate Thread Group
- Concurrency Thread Group
- Arrivals Thread Group
- Free-Form Arrivals Thread Group

There are multiple ways to validate the load.

- You can check in APM tool if you are using any.
- You can plot multiple graphs such as Hits Per Second, Response Time
  over time, Response Codes, Bytes Throughput, Connect Time and
  Latency and correlate with the time.